# Countdown app for Android that displays hours and not days, up to 100h and doesn't show ads in countdown

Tags: gratis, android

I'm looking for a countdown app for Android that:

- displays hours and not days
- countdowns till at least 100h
- doesn't show ads in countdown
- doesn't display some event name that can't be configured (eg "birthday"): I'd like to either not show any event name, or write it down myself.

Preference for a gratis application.

---

What I've tried so far:

1. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jupli.countdowntoanything shows days:

[image]

2. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.gira.widget.countdown displays days:

[image]

3. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.gira.widget.countdown has ads unless one pays for the premium version:

[image]

4. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.BirthdayCountdown only specializes in birthdays:

[image]

5. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kempmobil.timer and https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.cwiesner.android.visualtimer only go up to 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

One can use [Large Countdown timer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mta.countdown):

[image]

The application:

- displays hours and not days
- countdowns till 99h59min59sec
- doesn't show ads in countdown
- doesn't display any event name
- gratis